# LINQ query for sorting a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a collection of that type:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files;
```

I'm trying to sort the files so that all files with the name 'index.js' will appear at the beginning of the list. I don't mind how the rest of the files are sorted.

What would be the LINQ query for that  ?

Comment: @HenriCook: Why? What's wrong with `OrderBy`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method syntax**

```
files = files.OrderBy(x => x.Name == "index.js" ? 0 : 1);
```

**Query syntax**

```
files = from x in files
        orderby x.Name == "index.js" ? 0 : 1
        select x;
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Thank you, I cleaned it up

Comment: You could acually files.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "index.js");

Comment: OrderBy perfectly works with boolean keys, so it's no need to use ternary operator ;)

Comment: @2kay, i beat you to it :)

Comment: @AndreasJohansson It *works* but it's much less readable.  It's not intuitive that `true > false` and even if this code compiles, it's not clear to the reader whether the matching values should be at the start or at the end, so the added conditional operator is well worth the few additional characters.

Comment: that's great ! At first I was doing it with a custom IComparer, but this is so much neater :)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
var f = files.OrderBy(x => "index.js".Equals(x.Name) ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one "clever" way:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> ordered = files.OrderBy(x => "index.js".Equals(x.Name) ? 0 : 1);
```